# How to open a file in linux without specifiying editor?

Tags: shell, csh

I have emacs as my defualt editor in linux, and I also have alias in my .cshrc file.

- alias e "emacs -mm"

Sometime I just want to hit the file name in the command line and open it in emacs directly with out the editor beign metioned. 
Example instead of

- $ e foo.cc&

What I want is to open

- $foo.cc

May be this is lazy to do but it saves a lot time if you have so many files to handle. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can't do this unless you want to write your own shell.

Comment: If you run Emacs as a daemon, you can use `alias e "emacsclient -n"`. Then you can open files like: `$ e foo.cc` (saves you from typing the ampersand..)

Comment: Use emacs as your terminal :)

Comment: What if the file you seek to edit by typing only its name is executable?  What if its not executable, but there is an executable in your path with that name?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You probably cannot open a file with `$foo.cc` (and that would be ambiguous for a shell script `script.sh`: would `script.sh` means "edit the file `script.sh`" or "run the shell script `script.sh`" ?). However,

You might want to use [xdg-open](http://portland.freedesktop.org/xdg-utils-1.0/xdg-open.html), or the `$EDITOR` variable (see [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html)). If you always have a single `emacs` running, you might set `EDITOR` to `emacsclient` in your `~/.bashrc` (if using `/bin/bash`) or your `~/.zshrc` (if using `/bin/zsh`)

BTW many editors (including `emacs`, `gedit`, `vim`) are able to edit several files, i.e. `$EDITOR *.c`

And depending upon your login shell ([zsh](http://www.zsh.org/), [fish](http://fishshell.com/), or `bash`) you could set up a shell function or alias to simply type `e foo.c`; I feel that it is not worth the effort, since with autocompletion I just have to type 3 keys <kbd>e</kbd> <kbd>m</kbd> <kbd>tab</kbd> to get `emacs` (and often the up arrows are enough)

<sup>Actually I start only once every day `emacs` then open many files inside it (and also I compile inside `emacs`)</sup>

BTW, you should avoid `csh` since it is [considered harmful](http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/misc/csh.html). Install a good interactive shell (e.g. with `sudo aptitude install zsh zsh-doc`) and use once [chsh(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chsh) to make it your login shell.

Comment: In this particular issue, using the varaible $EDITOR is equal to writing "e" for emacs, (even longer) and can't solve my problem. I saw this post http://linuxcommando.blogspot.se/2009/05/open-file-from-command-line-using-its.html but open using xdg-open doesn't uses the default editor instead of the one I defined (i.e. emacs).

Comment: Thanks for help, this is not worth the time as you said.

Comment: Upgrading your shell to something reasonable (like `zsh`) is worth your time.

Comment: If xdg-open is not using the editor you want, then change you default editor with xdg-settings.  Setting the other relevant environment varibles, such as EDITOR, TEXEDIT and VISUAL to emacsclient will also ensure consistency in editors when you run some system utils which rely on an editor. It is also likely that if you set xdg-open to use emacsclient. Some file browsers and some session managers also provide a preferred applications or association facility where you can set the default application to be used when 'opening' files of specific types

Comment: The paper says: "Csh Programming Considered Harmful". Not "Csh interactive shell use considered harmful".

Comment: But in practice, you sometimes *program* your interactive shell. So I believe that `csh` is sometimes harmful (even if I used `csh` as my interactive shell in the previous century, on Sun workstations)